# What does the Greek for "be reconciled" mean in 2 Corinthians 5:20?

Tags: greek, 2-corinthians

The Greek word for reconciled in 2 Cor 5:20 is  καταλλάγητε and parsed an Aorist Passive Imperative - so why do most translations translate this as "be reconciled" giving the reader idea that we need to do something to be reconciled?

Here is [the context of 2 Cor 5:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%205%3A16-21&version=HCSB;SBLGNT) -

> 2 Cor 5 <sup>18</sup> Everything is from God, who reconciled us to Himself through Christ and gave us the ministry of reconciliation. <sup>19</sup> That is, in Christ, God was reconciling the world to Himself, not counting their trespasses against them, and He has committed the message of reconciliation to us. <sup>20</sup> Therefore, we are ambassadors for Christ, certain that God is appealing through us. We plead on Christ’s behalf, “**Be reconciled to God**.” <sup>21</sup> He made the One who did not know sin to be sin for us, so that we might become the righteousness of God in Him.<sub>[HCSB]</sub>

We learn that reconciliation happened in the past on the cross with God the Father making peace with the world by judging the all of world's sins in his Son and the Messiah Jesus Christ. No where in this passage does it indicate they we need to make peace with God.  It does indicate that there is a ministry of reconciliation which to me means that as Christians we have a ministry to tell everyone that God has already made peace through His Son with the world and in doing so are ambassadors for Christ.

My question focuses on this how is the Aorist Passive Imperative of καταλλάγητε  to be translated correctly? It would seem that because this verse is in the passive voice that the subject is the one receiving the action of someone else in this case the subject created beings in the world have had God reconcile them so is not this a command from Christ to receive what the Father has done through the Son that is a command for the world to receive the Peace God has made through the Cross of Jesus Christ?

Comment: This was merged into an existing question that is a duplicate so that the answers here also go there.

Comment: Also, welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) Please keep in mind that [this is not a Christian site](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/441/423). Be sure to [check out what makes us different from other sites that study the Bible](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423).